# Google play services missing in signed APK

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app with Drive API.

When I try to test the app on my tablet or smartphone it works.
Now I have to publish on Play Store my app so I signed the apk through Eclipse.
The problem is that after this operation the apk doesn't work.

At first I followed this tutorial:
Google Drive SDK: Writing your first Drive app on Android http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ied1CjJ0iP0&feature=share

So I downloaded, using Google plugin for Eclupse, Drive API v2
In libs folder of my project is present the google-play-services.jar

My proguard.cfg is this [I created this file because the default version was not working]:

```
-printmapping proguard.map
-renamesourcefileattribute ProGuard
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-optimizationpasses 8
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-libraryjars /libs/google-play-services.jar

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
-keep interface org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.api.client.json.jackson.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.api.client.json.jackson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.api.client.googleapis.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.api.client.googleapis.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.api.client.auth.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.api.client.auth.** { *; }
-keep class javax.annotation.** { *; }
-keep interface javax.annotation.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.api.client.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.api.client.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.api.services.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.api.services.** { *; }
-keep class org.achartengine.** { *; }
-keep interface org.achartengine.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android..** { *; }
-keep class com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.protobuf.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.protobuf.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.api.client.extensions.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.api.client.extensions.android.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.api.client.json.gson.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.api.client.json.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.core.** { *; }
-keep interface com.fasterxml.jackson.core.** { *; }
-keep class com.claudioilluminati.googleaccountstorage.** { *; }
-keep interface com.claudioilluminati.googleaccountstorage.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

When I check in Eclipse inside the DDMS perspective I can see this error:

```
The Google Play Services resources were not found. 
Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

I just want to add that the dimension of apk signed is smaller that apk not signed.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Claudio

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was including the jar and not the whole project (including resources).

Comment: How Did you include the whole project?